# Apache CXF Client for Dynamic Endpoints

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, client-side

I'm now using Apache CXF as a web services client for a .NET service to get around NTLM authentication.  It works great, but I'm wondering why I can't seem to be able to set the web service target endpoint.  CXF seems to want the WSDL at runtime for some strange reason - not sure.  It takes the physical endpoint from the WSDL, which works fine in test environments I guess, but at deployment time it's sure to change.

Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
        MyWebServices service = new MyWebServices ();
        MyWebServicesSoap port = service.getMyWebServicesSoap12();

        // Turn off chunking so that NTLM can occur
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
        httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

        port.doSomethingUseful();
```

Again, there is no place that I can see in the CXF client API that allows me to set the service endpoint.  Not that I can see anyway.  In this case, the target is http://localhost/integration/webservices/mywebservices.asmx, but I could be anywhere.  Surely this pedestrian problem is solved somehow?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MyWebServicesSoap port = service.getMyWebServicesSoap12();
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint);
```

Alternatively, `MyWebServices` might have other getXXX methods that take a URL for the WSDL location

Comment: In the MyServices class, are there other methods that will return a port that accept a URL parameter?  Can you edit your post to paste the signature of that class?

Comment: Seeing how the CXF team do things always makes me feel better about my own needlessly over-engineered code :)

Comment: ... aaaand I'm back here ... for the same G**D*** info. Unfortunately I can only give points once :)

Comment: What kind of object is "endpoint" ? A String containing the URL? A special EndPoint (or some similar class) instance?

Comment: From another example endpoint looks to be a simple String containing the URL for the new endpoint.

Answer (score 13):

Working in cxf 2.6.1

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
client.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, "http://some-valid-endpoint") ;
```

Comment: Thank you. You just saved me a day. This is the way to do it if you would like to use the generated factory class and change the end point address dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
String customerEndPoint = "https://localhost:8080/customerService/v1"

customerWebService = service.getCustomerWebServicePort();

((BindingProvider) customerWebService).getRequestContext()
                        .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                                customerEndPoint);
```